# Proof by Induction on a recursive function

Tags: proof-explanation, induction, recursion, recursive-algorithms

its been a while since I have done proofs and am struggling on a question:

Let $T(n)$ be defined recursively as follows: $T(1)=c$ and $T(n)=3T(n/3)+c, \forall n\geqslant 3$, where $c$ is some arbitrary positive constant and $n=3^k$ for some non-negative integer $k$. Prove by induction on $k$ that $T(n)=(3c)/(2) n - c/2$.

So far I have been able to break it down to the following:

- Base Case = $T(1) = c$
- Recursive Case = $T(n)=3T(n/3)+c$
- Since $n=3^k$ this makes the recursive case: $T(3^k) = 3T(3^{k-1})+c$

Beyond that I am struggling at where to start. I know I need to prove it for the lowest possible value i.i. $k=1$, which I think gives me:

$T(3)=3T(3/3)+c$

$= 3T(1)+c = 4c$

I don't think this is right though and don't really know why.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so you are only defining this function on powers of 3, correct?

Comment: @Alan to my knowladge yes given $n=3^k$ for non-negative integers of $k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are virtually there. The induction is really an induction on $k$ starting at $0$, to prove $T(n) = (3c/2)\cdot n - c/2$ where $n = 3^k$:
For the base case:

$$T(3^0) = T(1) = c = (3c/2)\cdot 3^0 - c/2$$

For the inductive step, the inductive hypothesis is:

$$T(3^k) = (3c/2)\cdot  3^k - c/2$$

and using this and the recursive definition, you get:

$$T(3^{k+1}) = 3T(3^k) + c =  3\left[(3c/2)\cdot  3^k - c/2\right] + c= (3c/2)\cdot 3^{k+1} - c/2$$

which completes the inductive proof

Comment: I'm sorry but how do you get $c=(3c/2)\cdot3^0 -c/2$, I was able to follow everything but that.

Comment: $3^0 = 1$. So $(3c/2)\cdot 3^0 - c/2 = 3c/2 - c/2 = c(3/2 - 1/2) = c$.

Comment: Got it thank you. Its pretty basic then. It's been a long time since I've done maths like this!